# After the Notes 11 upgrade i can not debug databases give apache poi libraries error

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I'm using Apache poi 1.3.1 library in many database for xpages export/import actions. when I upgrade notes 10 to 11 and notes 11 give me a library errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrade to Notes 11 - issue with Apache POI java library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66155713/upgrade-to-notes-11-issue-with-apache-poi-java-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I see that the library is installed but the compiler doesn't resolve the bundle, I expect that it's the Target Platform bug described here, with the workaround being to add the data/workspace/applications/eclipse directory to your TP: https://frostillic.us/blog/posts/2018/10/19/058650e080e352178525832b00519d2c . That recurs frequently during any upgrade involving 9.0.1FP10 through to current versions.

Comment: Hi jesse, thanks for your answer but it's not work.I added  target platform pic. same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66155713/upgrade-to-notes-11-issue-with-apache-poi-java-library

Comment: hi again jesse, after i copied poi files to client eclipse\plugin - feature folders and again debug its work by clearly. Many many thanks